# Not able to connect Nokia 6.1 Plus to Android Studio for running apps

Tags: android, linux, android-studio, debugging

I am using Nokia 6.1 Plus. I am trying to connect it to Android Studio for debugging apps. But I am not able to connect. I have enabled Developer Options, in that also enabled USB debugging. Selected default USB debugging to File Transfer. But  unable to find the device in Android Studio. 
**I am using Linux. Anybody help me to find the solution.

Comment: I think this is not perfect but you can fix it by this. Download this PDANet and install it. http://pdanet.co/install/

Answer (score 0):

You need adb driver for that.do below steps(Windows)

1. Download and install this(Universal
   adb driver ):https://adb.clockworkmod.com/
2. Goto My Computer Device Manager ,find your android device=>update driver=>select adb interface and press ok.

by doing this it will be resolved.

For Linux:follow this Link for adb setup:
[Linux Adb](https://www.xda-developers.com/install-adb-windows-macos-linux/)

Comment: I am using android in Cent Os 7.. where do I go adb interface

Comment: I haven't tried in Linux but this Link may help you.